# How do I get my entire layout to adjust to window size?

Tags: html, layout, tumblr

I have finally designed my tumblr the way I want it! The background image is built for the text to read only in the center section. The only problem is when the browser window is anything smaller than maximized, both the text and header adjusts to it but background stays the same. Does anyone know how to fix this in the html code (specifics would be nice, I'm totally new to this) Thank You!

Comment: Without seeing your code, it will be hard to fix it, right?

Comment: Is there a way I could send it to you? It's far too long for fit in the comment box (unless there's just one section you would need to see)

Comment: A link to the site, or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) could suffice.

Comment: BrendansDetour.tumblr.com is the link. Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do dynamic-resizing with javascript like this.

```
    var initialize = function() {
        var theBody = document.getElementById("bodyId");
        theBody.width = document.width;
    }

    window.onresize(function() {
        var theBody = document.getElementById("bodyId");
        theBody.width = document.width;
        });
```

In this example I'm resizing the entire body element, but you could apply it to whatever columns and fields you want.

```
<body id="bodyId" onload="initialize()">
...
</body>
```